# How to prevent bootstrap navbar from scrolling with the rest of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

in my angular single page app I have the following navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <!--<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">-->
                <a class="btn btn-navbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown">Customer Instances <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/itarList">iTAR</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/nonItarList">Non-iTAR</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Training & Documentation <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/videoTutorials">Video Tutorials</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/taskBasedHelp">Task-Based Help</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/documentTemplates">Document Templates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/artifactSamples">Artifact Samples</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Service Requests <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/viewExistingRequests">View Existing Requests</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/enterNewRequest">Enter New Request</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Development Tracker <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/viewBacklogItems">View Backlog Items</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/viewFeatureReleaseSchedule">View Feature Release Schedule</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/viewListOfSuggestedEnhancements">View List Of Suggested Enhancements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/suggetAnEnhancement">Suggest An Enhancement</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/viewActiveBugReports">View Active Bug Reports</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/reportABug">Report A Bug</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Site Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#/userAdministration">User Administration</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#/instanceAdministration">Instance Administration</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#/applicationAdministration">Application Administration</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                             </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I need to prevent this navbar from scrolling with the rest of the page.
When I try to add the navbar-fixed-top class attribute to the top-most  element, I do get the desired result, but, my right-most nav item (Site Administration) is being shifted down (or wrapped around), making the entire navbar twice the height.
Is there a way to achieve this scroll-free navbar without having such a side affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try removing the `container` div that's wrapping the navbar..

http://bootply.com/113435

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
                <!--<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">-->
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown">Customer Instances <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/itarList">iTAR</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/nonItarList">Non-iTAR</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Training &amp; Documentation <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/videoTutorials">Video Tutorials</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/taskBasedHelp">Task-Based Help</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/documentTemplates">Document Templates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/artifactSamples">Artifact Samples</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Service Requests <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/viewExistingRequests">View Existing Requests</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/enterNewRequest">Enter New Request</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Development Tracker <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/viewBacklogItems">View Backlog Items</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/viewFeatureReleaseSchedule">View Feature Release Schedule</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/viewListOfSuggestedEnhancements">View List Of Suggested Enhancements</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/suggetAnEnhancement">Suggest An Enhancement</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/viewActiveBugReports">View Active Bug Reports</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#/reportABug">Report A Bug</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Site Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                       ...
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                             </ul> 
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: @Zim your link seems to be broken or layout mismatch happend. Please repost answer by posting picture or something...

Comment: Bootply link works for me, but I've posted the HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

Elements will move onto a new line if there isn't space for them in the current one.

The only way you can stop them doing that is by making space for them on the desired line. Try reducing the size of the text slightly or removing some horizontal margins.

Bear in mind that anyone visiting your site on a smaller screen than you or even on a mobile or tablet will most likely see the element drop down as well.

Comment: There should be sufficient amount of space for all of my 6 top-level nav items to be on the same line. In fact, there all fit on the same line just fine (being positioned from the far left), before I add navbr-fixed-top. After I add navbar-fixed-top, the overall positioning shifts towards the center, at which point, the right-most elements wraps around. Is there a tag to make them all stratch across the full length?

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry I don't know about Bootstrap.